# Unexpected indent error when i try to run my code in python

Tags: python, server, ddos

I'm trying to make a simple dDos attack to server i'm hosting on my PC.
But when i launch this program it says me:

```
unexpected indent (<unknown>, line 14)
```

Code:

```
from scapy.all import *
source_IP = input("Enter IP address of Source: ")
target_IP = input("Enter IP address of Target: ")
source_port = int(input("Enter Source Port Number:"))
i = 1

while True:
   IP1 = IP(source_IP = source_IP, destination = target_IP)
   TCP1 = TCP(srcport = source_port, dstport = 80)
   pkt = IP1 / TCP1
   send(pkt, inter = .001)
   
   print ("packet sent " + i)
      i = i + 1
```

How i can fix that?

EDIT:

now code display this:

```
Undefined variable 'send'
Undefined variable 'TCP'
Undefined variable 'IP'
Unable to import 'scapy.all'
```

...

Comment: The last line has to be on the same indentation level as the one before.

Comment: @KlausD., thanks! but i made some edit.

Comment: The problem is that your python env is not able to import scapy.all. Check if that file is in the same location as the script.